# Jquery concatenate string with space on modal load

Tags: jquery

i have a input box firstname and lastname. when button clicked, a modal will show and populate a input box name fullname but has a space in it.

example: "marvin" and "castro" => button clicked => "marvin castro"

but all i get is this, "marvincastro"

my code is here

```
   $("#submit").click(function () {
            $("#register").modal('show');

            $("#inputfname").text($('#fname').val() + $('#lname').val());
   });
```

if i do like this,

```
   $("#submit").click(function () {
            $("#register").modal('show');

            $("#inputfname").text($('#fname').val()+ $(' ').val() + $('#lname').val());
   });
```

the output is like this: "marvinundefinedcastro"

thanks in advance

Comment: Replace `$(' ').val()` with `' '`. It will add a space between first and last name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $("#submit").click(function () {
            $("#register").modal('show');

            $("#inputfname").text($('#fname').val() + " " + $('#lname').val());
   });
```

Don't complicate it, just add a space between them.

Comment: my God. always the simple ones. thanks for the answer.